# Need to find the name for the one of the condition in software "thread never get a chance to resume"

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns

I'm just looking for the conventional name for the typical software problem:
"thread never get a chance to resume"
in the case of a large multi-threading environment in a heavy load one of the threads tries to proceed with some task but can't because the other threads keep pushing this thread out from doing the work.

I'm NOT looking for the solution of this generic software problem, just checking if there is a simple common name which can be used to refer to this problem?

Comment: Starvation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)

Comment: I think that you are talking about "starvation"

Comment: "starvation" is too generic term: It can be "resource starvation", or "thread starvation" etc. For example "thread starvation" could mean completely different and therefore confusing